# Swapping two columns in a 2D list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

what would be the quickest way to get to :

```
[[0, 2, 0, 0],\
[0, 2, 0, 0],\
[0, 2, 0, 0],\
[0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

from:

```
[[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

without using numpy or any other external library

Comment: SO is no code writing service. Please post what you've tried so far to solve the problem. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: i know how to solve this particular case, my problem is moving items to the left or right when a sublist contains multiple ones. (e.g.:[[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 0],\
[0, 0, 2, 2]]   this is why im trying to find out if there is a general piece of code for this

Comment: What do you expect as the output for `[0, 0, 2, 0],\ [0, 0, 2, 0],\ [0, 0, 2, 0],\ [0, 0, 2, 2]] `?

Comment: N.B. that `zip(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) -> [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]`, so `zip(*rows) -> columns`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a list `l`, which is `[0, 0, 2, 0]`, and we want to shift all the elements one place to left.

Firstly, we need to get all the elements to the right except the first one. List slicing `l[1:]` would work here, which would get `[0, 2, 0]`.

Secondly, we need to get the remaining elements on the left with `l[1:]`, which would get `[0]`.

You can now probably see that we can shift the elements one place to the left with adding the above 2 lists together:

```
>>> lst = [0, 0, 2, 0]
>>> first = lst[1:]
>>> second = lst[:1]
>>> first + second
[0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Which can be summarized in this function:

```
def shift(lst, n):
    return lst[n:] + lst[:n]
```

Since this can shift one lists position, it can applied to all lists in a nested list and shift their positions to left by 1:

```
nested_lst = [shift(sublist, 1) for sublist in nested_lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific task:

```
l = [[0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0]]

for arr in l:
    arr[1], arr[2] = arr[2], arr[1]
```